# robocopy script help - different sources and detinations

Tags: replication, robocopy

I need a robocopy script that can run to replicate data from a source to a destination. the problem I have is I need to replicate certain folders from the source from different drives over to a destination server which will need to go to different drives also.

I'm using this script to copy a single folder over to the destination server (which this is running on)

```
@echo off 
SET Day=%date:~6,4%.%date:~3,2%.%date:~0,2% 

SET _source=\\10.10.10.18\R$\User\customer1

SET _target=E:\customer1

SET _log=E:\test_%Day%_Replication_Log.txt 


SET _what=/MIR /COPYALL /B

SET _options=/NS /NC /NFL /NDL /R:0 /W:0 /RH:0615-1730 /MON:900 /MOT:30 /LOG+:"%_log%" 

robocopy %_source% %_target% %_what% %_options%
```

I have a number of folders on the R drive as well as other drives that I wish to copy like this but I ideally dont want separate jobs for each and would like to run it under one batch file if possible.

Is there a way of having the source location specified in a text document and having the script read this and pass it to the command same would I also be able to specify the destination for this data i.e.:

customer1 - e drive

customer2 - f drive 
etc

I would like this as easy as possible so that folders can be added / removed from the text file so the commands don't need to be altered.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are going to need to do something like the following..

```
SET _source=\\10.10.10.18\R$\User\customer1
rem SET _source=C:\windows
SET _target=E:\customer1
SET _log=E:\test_%Day%_Replication_Log.txt 
SET _what=/MIR /COPYALL /B
SET _options=/NS /NC /NFL /NDL /R:0 /W:0 /RH:0615-1730 /MON:900 /MOT:30 /LOG+:"%_log%" 

for /f "tokens=1*delims=-" %%a in ('dir /B/ad/s %_source%\drive*') do (
robocopy %%a %_target% %_what% %_options%
)
pause
```

Now, what I suspect you are going to need to do is something like the following..

Notice the oddball: "%~p0" - if you go to CMD (command line) and type in FOR /? - it will explain what these mean..  It like two or three screens in on the help..

```
SET _source=\\10.10.10.18\R$\User\customer1
rem SET _source=C:\windows
SET _target=E:\customer1
SET _log=E:\test_%Day%_Replication_Log.txt 
SET _what=/MIR /COPYALL /B
SET _options=/NS /NC /NFL /NDL /R:0 /W:0 /RH:0615-1730 /MON:900 /MOT:30 /LOG+:"%_log%" 

for /f "tokens=1*delims=-" %%a in ('dir /B/ad/s %_source%\drive*') do (
cd "%~p0%_source%\drive"
copy *.txt "%~p0 %_source%\drive"
FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN ('type %~p0ALIST.txt') do (
rem cd "%~p0%%A\%_target%"
rem copy *.txt "%~p0%%A\%_target%"
robocopy %%a %_target% %_what% %_options%
rem cd "%~p0%%A\drive"
)
pause
```